# Get Names instead of IDs

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, xampp

I have a table `product_sales` which contains foreign keys of other tables i.e customer_id(of `customers` table) and measurement_id(of `measurements` table). Now I want to get Names of customers and measurements instead of IDs.

`product_sales` table:
id, customers_id, measurement_id

`customers` table:
id, customer_name

`measurements` table:
id, measurement_name

I tried this
`SELECT product_sales.sale_id , customers.name, measurement_id product_sales.created_at, product_sales.total  FROM` product_sales `INNER JOIN customers on customers.id = product_sales.customers_id`

Comment: So what have you tried? Can you show us any code?

Comment: @Peppermintology Yes I did but not worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

product_sales  is a bridge table, so you can joinboth other taBLES TO IT

```
SELECT c.*,m.* 
FROM customers  c INNER JOIN product_sales  ps ON c.id = p.customers_id
INNER JOIN measurements  m ON p.measurement_id = m.id
```

Comment: OK I got it. Thanks a lot